# Adding a file to list item using ajax

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, ajax

For adding attachment via ajax I used this code from https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest
:
and added "for" and iffy function to make it unique to all files.

```
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        // IFFY to save the current index
        (function (x) {
            var file = files[x];
            lastFileName = file.name;
            var fileName = Date.now() + file.name;
            var getFileBuffer = function (file) {
                //alert('in getFileBuffer');
                var deferred = NWF$.Deferred();
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
                }
                reader.onerror = function (e) {
                    deferred.reject(e.target.error);
                }
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
                return deferred.promise();
            };


            getFileBuffer(file).then(function (buffer) {
                //alert(buffer);
                NWF$.ajax({
                    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listName + "')/items('" + idVal + "' ) / AttachmentFiles / add(FileName = '" + fileName + "')",
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: "Contents of file",
                    data: buffer,
                    processData: false,
                    headers: {
                        "ACCEPT": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                        "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                        "X-RequestDigest": document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value
                        // "content-length": buffer.byteLength
                    }, //end headers
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        var fileUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + data.d.ServerRelativeUrl;
                        NWF$('#displayFiles tr:last').after('<tr><td><a class="fileLink" href="' + fileUrl + '">' + lastFileName + '</a> '
                            + '</td><td><a class="removeHyper">מחיקה &times</a></td></tr>');
                        filesItems.push(_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + data.d.ServerRelativeUrl);
                        NWF$('#' + filesList).text(converAddressToString(filesItems))
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        console.log("err " + data.d);
                    }
                });
            })
        })(i)
```

The problem is that I need to add a folder of the attachement id before.

```
        NWF$.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listName + "')/items",
        method: "POST",
        body: { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Folder' }, 'ServerRelativeUrl': _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/Lists/stamList/Attachments/' +idVal},
        headers: {
            "ACCEPT": "application/json; odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value
        }, //end headers
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log("err");
        }

    });
```

And THAT is not working :( that's why the item is not added.
What do you think? how to add folder named idval in the attachment?

Answer (score 1):

This is the working code for uploading files to item :)

```
var filesItems = []
```

var file
var table = ""
var listName = "stamList"
var item = NWF$("#getFile")
NWF.FormFiller.Events.RegisterAfterReady(function () {
    NWF$("#getFile").on('change', function () {
        var idVal = NWF$("#" + itemID).val();

```
    var files = this.files;
    NWF$.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listName + "')/items",
        method: "POST",
        body: { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Folder' }, 'ServerRelativeUrl': _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/Lists/stamList/Attachments/' + idVal },
        headers: {
            "ACCEPT": "application/json; odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value
        }, //end headers
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log("err");
        }

    });

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        setTimeout((function (x) {
            var file = files[x];
            var lastFileName = file.name;
            var fileName = Date.now() + file.name;
            var getFileBuffer = function (file) {
                //alert('in getFileBuffer');
                var deferred = NWF$.Deferred();
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
                }
                reader.onerror = function (e) {
                    deferred.reject(e.target.error);
                }
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
                return deferred.promise();
            };


            getFileBuffer(file).then(function (buffer) {
                //alert(buffer);
                NWF$.ajax({
                    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listName + "')/items('" + idVal + "')/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName = '" + fileName + "')",
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: "Contents of file",
                    data: buffer,
                    processData: false,
                    headers: {
                        "ACCEPT": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                        "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                        "X-RequestDigest": document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value
                        // "content-length": buffer.byteLength
                    }, //end headers
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        var fileUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + data.d.ServerRelativeUrl;
                        NWF$('#displayFiles tr:last').after('<tr><td><a class="fileLink" href="' + fileUrl + '">' + lastFileName + '</a> '
                            + '</td><td><a class="removeHyper">מחיקה &times</a></td></tr>');
                        filesItems.push(_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + data.d.ServerRelativeUrl);
                        NWF$('#' + filesList).text(convertAddressToString(filesItems))
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        console.log("err " + data.d);
                    }
                });
            })
        })(i), 100*i);
        // IFFY to save the current index


    }
    NWF$("#displayFiles").on('click', '.removeHyper', function (e) {
        var idRow = NWF$(this).closest('tr').index() - 1;
        if (idRow >= 0) {
            console.log(idRow);
            filesItems.splice(idRow, 1)
            NWF$('#' + filesList).text(convertAddressToString(filesItems))
        }
        NWF$(this).closest('tr').remove()
    })

    function convertAddressToString(array) {
        return array.join('\n');
    }
})
```

})